# Is there any R function equivalent to mlab.psd of python?

Tags: python, r

I am trying to replicate the following python code in R :

```
data_psd, freqs = mlab.psd(data, Fs = fs, NFFT = NFFT, window=psd_window, noverlap=NOVL).
```

I couldn't find a proper function in r to perform the above code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PSD](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psd/versions/2.1.0) library.

> Adaptive, sine multitaper power spectral density estimation for R

Install:

```
install.packages("psd")
```

[Documentaion](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psd/versions/2.1.0)